# Is the debt forgiven if the lender forgot?

Tags: sharia, money, debt

I recently came to know the [seriousness of having debts](http://islamqa.info/en/71183) before dying.

What if the situation arises where I borrow a very small amount of money, say the amount equal to the cost of a candy and after about an year or so, if I try to pay him back and if he says "I don't remember lending you any money." In this situation, is the debt forgiven ? Can I keep that money or should I donate to charity?

Comment: I would consider **convincing** him that he did lend me the money, and ask him about his decision in that regard, either to take it back, or forgive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debt is debt, and if you are certain you lend something or some money from someone you are supposed to pay it back in all situations. It does not matter what is its value.
 So if someone has forgotten lending you something, what you can do is, as mentioned in a comment, convince him about lending you, if he does not remember and refuses to take, than ask him to forgive it. This is the best way.

Comment: What if the person suffers from memory loss? Asking to forgive makes sense to me when he very well remembers me giving. Other wise, I feel it is not good.

Comment: If he is not accepting in any way that he has given you any loan, and he is not willing to take anything from you, than this is the last thing to do to be safe. If you think memory loss is such that he is not able to do his daily dealings and someone else is taking care of his matters, you can return your money to that person.

Answer (score 0):

aww,

insist that the person DID lend it you. If he refuses, give it to him as a gift, or buy him something of the same value, and then, just in case,  donate to the poor.

wwb

Comment: Even after giving / paying him back, why do I have to donate to the poor (just in case)?

Comment: He does not mean if he has accepted than donate to poor. But even for that if he is not accepting it, i think you should ask him to forgive first than consider donating if your heart is not satisfied.